# I keep getting a permission denied error when running a command with sudo

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I am following this tutorial that uses go ethereum
[tut](https://docs.goquorum.consensys.net/en/latest/HowTo/GetStarted/GettingStartedOverview/#quickstart-with-quorum-wizard)

but when I run the following command I get a permission denied error

```
sudo bootnode --nodekey=new-node-1/nodekey --writeaddress > new-node-1/enode
```

this is the error

```
-bash: new-node-1/enode: Permission denied
```

Comment: This might help: `sudo bootnode --nodekey=new-node-1/nodekey --writeaddress | sudo tee new-node-1/enode >/dev/null`

Comment: Thankyou I already tried a pipe in the end It ran with taking the > symbol out. tbh I dont what the > is in bash

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` runs `bootnode` with root privileges, but the `> new-node-1/enode` redirection will still attempt to write into the `new-node-1/` with your user privileges. You might want to check if you have write permissions for `new-node-1/`, and give them to yourself if not.

If you don't care about `new-node-1/enode` belonging to root (as opposed to you), then you can switch to root to run the entire command:

```
sudo su -
bootnode --nodekey=new-node-1/nodekey --writeaddress > new-node-1/enode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your command in `bash -c`:

```
sudo bash -c "bootnode --nodekey=new-node-1/nodekey --writeaddress > new-node-1/enode"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo bootnode --nodekey=new-node-1/nodekey --writeaddress new-node-1/enode
```

this is what got it working in the end. I just ran the same command without the '>'. I dont know what it did or why it worked.